# Cross Platform Desktop Application Development

Tags: macos, windows-8, desktop-application

I’d like to develop Windows 8 applications and have them hosted on Azure as if they were any other website, i.e. accessible to Macs, PCs, etc. I don’t want to be limited to people downloading Windows 8 applications to a Windows 8 PC or device. Can you explain how Azure achieves this?

I’d like to develop Windows 8 applications for desktops, but not be limited to running them on Windows 8 PCs and devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Azure doesn't achieve this at all, other than providing a public endpoint for access to 'code'.  What you have up in the cloud will depend on what you want to achieve and who you want to reach.

You mention web site and application, but those connote two very different architectures.

A **web site** will give you the most reach since you'll (presumably) be using standards like HTML5/JavaScript and CSS that are available on a multitude of platforms.  As you can see by using applications like outlook.com, the user experience can be quite immersive.  With a web site there's little to no client-side requirements other than a browser.

An **application** typically implies native installation on the target machine and provides the richest possible experience because you use techniques, frameworks, and APIs that are specific to a platform or a device.  Applications also (arguably better than web sites) enable reach and monetization via marketplaces like Apple's App Store, Google Play, and the Window Store.

Technologies like Silverlight and Flash were part of the RIA wave (Rich Internet Application) that was a hybrid of both: use the web for reach, and a plug-in for richness.  Those are still valid models, but the tide is shifting to HTML5 which is now much closer to reality and narrows the user experience gap that Silverlight and Flash filled.  While Silverlight is definitely supported (in an out-of-browser mode as well), the choice of using a plug-in technology will limit your audience because of platforms supported and the need for an additional installation.  That may or may not be acceptable given your target application.

What we are seeing now is a trend toward mobile application development paradigms - native still, of course, but also hybrid applications such as afforded by PhoneGap, AppMobi, Sencha, and other HTML5 frameworks and cross-platform options like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com).  Each of these allows you to develop in the language and constructs you know well for a given platform, but create applications which are partially or wholly 'native' and can run on multiple devices and platforms.  Typically, you will reuse much of your 'back-end' and data integration layers across you targeted platforms, but rework the user interface to be in-line with the expectation for the device.

Windows Azure figures prominently in the development of such apps by providing infrastructure for data storage, services, identity management, push notifications, and other facilities that rely on centralization and scale.

And I suppose there's one other option in all this, virtualization, but that's a larger hurdle for end users and wouldn't recommend that as a general approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Silverlight apps, it runs in browser. So it can be open Windows PC as well as in Mac. Do visit [Microsoft Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) website. Here's few links regarding Azure with Silverlight.

[Silverlight in the Azure cloud](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-in-the-Azure-cloud-Part-1.aspx)

[Microsoft Silverlight 5 and Windows Azure Enterprise Integration](http://www.silverlightshow.net/book/Microsoft-Silverlight-5-and-Windows-Azure-Enterprise-Integration.aspx)

[Windows Azure with Silverlight End To End Demo](http://friendssharestuff.codeplex.com/)

More you google, more you will get results.